# exportar a excel a partir de un byte[] en angular

Tags: angular, blob, exportar, byte

Tengo el json de respuesta del backend (spring boot):

```
private byte[] archivoExcel;
private String extension;
private String mime;
```

Lo que necesito en angular es obtener este byte[] y exportarlo a excel, para ello mi json de respuesta en angular es:

```
export class RespuestaExportar {
    archivoExcel: ArrayBuffer;
    extension: string;
    mime: string;
}
```

y en mi archivo component.ts tengo:

```
this.reversionesService.getReversionesExportarSeguimiento(this.solicitud).subscribe(res => {
  this.respuestaExportar=res;
  let file = new Blob([this.respuestaExportar.archivoExcel], { type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"});            
  var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  window.open(fileURL);
}
```

cuando ejecuto el boton 'exportar', realiza el consumo correctamente, y realiza la descarga del excel, pero dicho archivo esta dañado.
Requiero un paso mas para solucionarlo? o existe otra alternativa, ya que necesito obtener este byte[] desde el backEnd.

Comment: ¿Cómo mandas el fichero desde el backend? ¿Lo serializas en un JSON?

Comment: En realidad lo que falta es definir los headers en el backend para su consumo, ya que en el codigo que presento esta en el frontEnd (Angular)

Comment: Lo pregunto porque no entiendo la clase RespuestaExportar, cómo creas una instancia de ella en frontend, con los datos recibidos.

Comment: De esta manera: respuestaExportar: RespuestaExportar;

Comment: entonces en el metodo obtengo el resultado asi: this.respuestaExportar=res;